# how to prevent multiple click and submit on ZK button?

Tags: java, mvvm, zk

My button on zul file using MVVM.

```
<button id="ok" label="OK" onClick="@command('vm.myCommand')"/>
```

my vm

```
@Command
public void myCommand(){
    System.out.println('my command clicked');
}
```

It display twice when I double click on my button. How to prevent this?

Comment: in the event handler disable the button for a short period of time

Comment: pleas give me a sample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `autodisable` attribute of button please have a look below code.

```
<zk>
    <button id="ok" label="OK" autodisable="self" />
</zk>
```

You can run this code in [zk Fiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/obi1o1/1-autodisable-for-button)  .When you click on button it automatically disable itself and when action is done it enable again.

Not related to your concrete problem but [ZK Progree Bar](http://zkframeworkhint.blogspot.in/2013/06/how-to-change-zk-progress-bar-text.html) another option to prevent user click after any action performed by user.